# Notation: $\mathbb{P}(N(t) = n)$ unconditional on $t$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, notation

*This is a question about notation. I find good notation always helps with thinking clearly.*

---

Consider a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$, and let $N(t)$ be the number of occurrences at time $t \geq 0$. Then $N \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda t)$, i.e.
$$ \mathbb{P}(N(t) = n) = \frac{(\lambda t)^n e^{-\lambda t}}{n!} $$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. This pmf is a function of two variables. If $T$ were a random variable independent of $N$ then
$$ \mathbb{P}(N(t) = n \ \vert \ T = t) = \mathbb{P}(N(t) = n) . $$
My question: would it be accurate (or at least make sense) that the probability of $N(t)$ *unconditional* on $T$ be written as
$$ \mathbb{P}(N = n) ? $$
If so, the law of total probability would allow us to write
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{P}(N = n) &= \int_{S_T} \mathbb{P}(N(t) = n \ \vert \ T = t) \ \mathbb{P}(T = t) \ dt \\
    &= \int_{S_T} \mathbb{P}(N(t) = n) \ \mathbb{P}(T = t) \ dt .
\end{align}

Comment: I would rather go for $N(T)$. Further if $T$ is a rv having continuous distribution then $P(T=t)=0$ for every $t$ so that your integrand is zero. Here $P(T=t)$ must be replaced by the PDF of $T$ (if it exists): $$P(N(T)=n)=\int_0^{\infty} P(N(T)=n\mid T=t)f_T(t)dt=\int_0^{\infty}P(N(t)=n)f_T(t)dt$$

Comment: @drhab I see. What if $T$ partitions $N(t)$? (That is, all the possible values of $T$ produce all possible values of $N(t)$.) Would it make sense to write $\mathbb{P}(N = n)$ then?

Comment: @drhab Also why have you replaced $\mathbb{P}(T = t)$ with $f_T(t)$? Isn't $\mathbb{P}(T = t)$ a function of $t$?

Comment: I wrote $f_T(t)$ in the extended of my remark that $T$ might be a continuous rv. Then $f_T$ denotes the density of $T$. Of course $P(T=t)$ is a function but the set $\{t|mid P(t)>0\}$ has measure zero, so that the integration that you propose will also take value zero.